# How to set up netbios aliases on smbd / nmbd

Tags: linux, samba, netbios

The hostname of my server is slightly unfriendly (let's say *b4dn4me*). I want my users to be able to access the server under a nicer name (let's say *bonnie*).

Samba is installed just to be able to respond to windows netbios name queries (just need nmbd), not to run a windows fileshare.

In the smb.conf file you can add a line:

```
netbios aliases = bonnie <alias2>
```

I had the idea that since we can specify a netbios name, I could use that as an 'alias' instead

```
netbios name = bonnie
```

Neither of the above work, though I can connect to *b4dn4me* with no problem.

I tried enabling/disabling the lines `wins support` and `wins server`

I don't want anything fancy, like binding to different interfaces (eth0:1 eth0:2) or different configs depending on what name was used to access the server. All the [material](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/cfgsmarts.html) I found on the interwebs regarding this so far, have this type of complicated set-up.

All I want the server to respond to *bonnie* as well as *b4dn4me*.

Answer (score 0):

It should work with just your first config i.e. `netbios aliases = alias1, alias2, ...`

In my experience at least...
After rebooting your server you should see the aliases pop up in the network..